# How to configure com.arjuna.ats.jta.orphanSafetyInterval in Jboss

Tags: jboss, transactions, ejb-3.0, database-replication, jta

I'm getting XARecovery Exception due to mysql replication breaks.

```
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local 
XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_NOTA: 
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException: XAER_NOTA: Unknown XID
```

Default timeout is 10 sec.
How to increase to orphanSafetyInterval timeout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property can be applied in standalone-full.xml under system property

```
 <system-properties>
    <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.orphanSafetyInterval" value="50000"/>
    <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.xaAssumeRecoveryComplete" value="true"/>
 </system-properties>
```

Moreover you also use xaAssumeRecoveryComplete to handle unknown id error while xa transaction

For more info please go through below link:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/development_guide/limitations_of_the_xa_recovery_process

Answer (score 1):

You can add *orphanSafetyInterval* as a *System Variable*, for example:

`-Dcom.arjuna.ats.jta.common.orphanSafetyInterval=20000`